# Calculate MTD using CTE and Projected Sales in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add MTD Sales in a SQL Query. I figured out how to do that with JOINS but i want to use a CTE to calculate MTD sales and then use that to calculate projected_sales.Formula for projected sales is (`MTD/wkdaysinmonth*wkdaystodate`)[which is also stored in CTE Table). Is there a way to make it easy? I wrote the following code;

Input:

```
Email            PaymentAmount     orderdate
xyz@gmail.com    10                11/01/2018
xyz@gmail.com    20                11/09/2018
```

sample output:

```
EmailAddress      MTD    Projected_sales
xyz@gmail.com      30        0.19
```

where Projected sales is calculated as number of days `passed=7` and total number of business days in *november 22*. {`[30/7*22]=0.19`} (`Present date = 11/09/2018`)

```
with dates as(
    select dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())) as startofmonth,
    dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())))) as endofmonth,
    convert(date,getdate()) as today
)
,daycounts as(
    select dates.*,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, endofmonth) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, endofmonth) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, endofmonth) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wkdaysinmonth,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, today) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, today) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, today) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wkdaystodate

    from dates
) 
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.EmailAddress as email,
o1.YTD
FROM
    Customers
INNER JOIN
        Orders
        ON
        Orders.CustomerID= Customers.CustomerID
JOIN
(SELECT 
c.EmailAddress,
SUM(Orders.PaymentAmount) AS YTD
FROM
Customers c
JOIN 
Orders
ON c.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
WHERE
Orders.OrderDate  BETWEEN '01/01/2018 00:00' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY
EmailAddress) AS o1 ON o1.EmailAddress = Customers.EmailAddress
WHERE
Orders.OrderDate  >= (GETDATE()-7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use cte recursive create a calendar table for `orderdate` startDate to endDate.

Then `OUTER JOIN` base on calendar table and do condition aggregate function in subquery get workdate.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT email, 
                Dateadd(day, 1, Eomonth(Min(orderdate), -1)) minDt, 
                Dateadd(day, 1, Eomonth(Max(orderdate)))     maxDt 
         FROM   t 
         GROUP  BY email 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT email, 
                Dateadd(day, 1, mindt), 
                maxdt 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  Dateadd(day, 1, mindt) < maxdt), 
     cte2 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Count(CASE 
                        WHEN Datename(dw, t1.mindt) NOT IN ('Sunday', 'Saturday' ) 
                      THEN 
                        1 
                      END) OVER( ORDER BY t1.mindt) workdt 
         FROM   cte t1) 
SELECT t1.email, 
       t2.total, 
       Max(diffdt) / ( Max(workdt) * Max(workdtmax) * 1.0 ) Projected_sales 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Max(workdt) 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY email 
                   ORDER BY workdt DESC) workdtMax, 
               Datediff(day, Min(mindt) OVER(partition BY email ORDER BY workdt) 
               , Max(mindt)  OVER(partition BY email ORDER BY workdt DESC))   + 1      diffdt 
        FROM   cte2) t1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT email, 
                         Sum(paymentamount) total, 
                         Min(orderdate)     minDt, 
                         Max(orderdate)     maxDt 
                  FROM   t 
                  GROUP  BY email) t2 
              ON t1.mindt BETWEEN t2.mindt AND t2.maxdt 
                 AND t1.email = t2.email 
WHERE  t2.total IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY t1.email, 
          t2.total
```

[sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/BWI26744)

**Reuslt**

```
email           total   Projected_sales
xyz@gmail.com   30      0.19480519480519
```

Comment: @D-Shih...Thanks for getting back..I am getting an error invalid object name t. In actual my emailaddress data is coming from customers table and date and payment amount is coming from orders table and both are related to each other by customerid. How can i use that in your query?

Comment: You can try to let `customers` instead of `T` in my query

Comment: @D-Shih..I have changed customers in top t, but in bottom where a left join is used how can join customers and orders table both? as i am getting payment amount from orders table.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a "calendar" table that has the weekdays for each day in the month.

Your calculation for the projected doesn't make sense to me.  So, I've also included what I consider to be a better calculation:

```
with dates as (
      select distinct dte,
             (case when datename(weekday, dte) not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') then 1 else 0 end) as num_weekdays,
            dte as month_start
      from t cross apply
           (values (dateadd(day, 1 - day(orderdate), orderdate))) v(dte)
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, d.dte),
             (case when datename(weekday, dte) not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') then 1 else 0 end) + num_weekdays,
             d.month_start
      from dates d
      where dte < dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, month_start))
     ),
     d as (
      select d.*, max(num_weekdays) over (partition by month_start) as month_weekdays
      from dates d
     )
select d.month_start, t.email,
       sum(paymentamount) as mtd,
       sum(paymentamount) * max(month_weekdays) / max(d.num_weekdays) as my_projected,
       sum(paymentamount) * 1.0 / (max(month_weekdays) * max(d.num_weekdays)) as your_projected
from t join
     d
     on t.orderdate = d.orderdate
group by d.month_start, t.email;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=938444fcd10e294acf8cbe27328359f7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: ..Thanks for replying back. I am getting an error invalid object name t. In actual my emailaddress data is coming from customers table and date and payment amount is coming from orders table and both are related to each other by customerid. How can i use that in your query?

Comment: @garry . . . `t` represents what you call "input" in your question.  It is not clear to me how this relates to your much more complicated query.

Comment: so my input is coming from two table customers and orders. how i will use that

Comment: @garry . . . Just add a CTE and call it `t`.  Be sure it is the first CTE defined in the query.